# How to securely open a folder using .NET without user input?

Tags: .net

I would like to open a folder using .NET and it seems like as if Process.Start is the way to go: [Open a folder using Process.Start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132422).

I already read [How to securely use Process.Start?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/57556/) but it deals with user input and was answered almost six years ago, it might be outdated.

I have a certain path like the following which is **not** based on any user input:

- C:\Users\cow
- C:\Users\cow\

What I already learned is to check whether the path is acually a folder path i.e. ends with a backslash. Another workaorund would be to specify "explorer.exe" directly. I decided to do both and came up with the following:

```
var path = @"C:\Users\cow";
if (!path.EndsWith(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString()))
{ //To avoid things like C:\Users\cow.exe
    path += Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;
}
Process.Start("explorer.exe", path);
```

What else should I take in consideration?

Comment: It depends on how/why you want to open the folder. There are several file dialogue components in .Netyou can use. You can also use URI handlers for this. I think this is a XY problem and  you're asking the wrong question, you would be better off asking "How do I achieve $context specific file/folder operation on stack overflow".

Comment: @wireghoul I want to open the folder so that the user does not have to navigate to this folder. I don't want to make any further actions after that, it's up to the user. We also show the path to the user, so he/she could open the path on his/her own, but our users should focus on our application rather than opening paths.